# Javascript NaN function

Tags: javascript

This function receive values for another one (the generation parameter). My objective is return onde array in cloneGene variable, although it appears like NaN and I do not know why.

```
function SampleWithReposition(generation, newGeneration) {
   newGeneration = [];
   generation = Starting_generation; 
   var randomGeneration = Math.floor(Math.random() * pop_size) + 0;

     for(i=0;i<pop_size;i++){
           newGeneration = generation[i] = generation[randomGeneration];

        }

       return newGeneration;
       GenerationStep(newGeneration);
       //document.write(newGeneration + ' <br />' + ' <br />');

    }


//Mutation and recombination rate
 function GenerationStep (mutation_rate, recombination_rate, generation, cloneGene) {
//var generation = [1, 2, 1, 54, 1, 1, 1];
generation = SampleWithReposition();
mutation_rate = recombination_rate = 0.1;

for(var i=0; i<pop_size; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<gene_size; j++){
        random_number = random();
        var max_individual = Math.max.apply(Math, generation);

            //mutation_rate
            if(random_number < mutation_rate){
                var cloneGene = 1;
                cloneGene=generation[i][j]=generation[max_individual][j]+1;

                    document.write(cloneGene);


            }

   }
```

}

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question but if I were you I would try to see if `generation[max_individual][j]` is a `Number` and not a `String`, if so maybe the problem is in `SampleWithReposition()`.

Comment: @Alberto: It rather is `undefined` than a string, otherwise it would not become `NaN`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that `"1" + 1 = 11` :D

Comment: SO, what are your sugestions?

Comment: What exactly does `SampleWithReposition()` return? If it's a 1d array you shouldn't try to access it like a 2d array..

Comment: creates a variable newgeneration that contain an array wuth 7 posititions, this functions selction a random number of this array and return it

Comment: will post this function