# Math max function

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the max number of an array [i], although with this function when i add the [i] the max_individual = NaN and not the max number of array and I do not why. Then I add 1 to the max_number of this array if the condition is validated.

Below is the code.

```
pop_size=3;
gene_size=7;

var cloneGene = 1;
  for(var i=0; i<pop_size; i++){
     generation[i]=new Array(gene_size);
     var max_individual = Math.max.apply(Math, generation[i]);
     for(var j=0;j<gene_size; j++){
         generation[i][j]=1;
         random_number = random();

     //mutation_rate
         if(random_number < mutation_rate){
    cloneGene = generation[i][j]=generation[i][j]+1;

    document.write(cloneGene);
             }
           }
       }
```

Comment: What is `random()`? Is that a function you've written? If you can put this on jsfiddle it would be easier.

Comment: Is this a dupe of your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854296/javascrip-nan-function?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array);
```

So probably take off the `[i]`.

```
Math.max.apply(Math, generation);
```

Comment: But `generation[i] = new Array(gene_size);`

Comment: Yeah. when you are trying to pass in `generation[i]` to the `Math.max.apply` it is empty. How can you get anything from it?

Comment: My point being that if you pass in `generation` you're passing in an array of arrays that's always increasing in size.

Comment: That's true. Hmm... Guess I don't understand whats going on then. The OP will never get a number by using Math.max.apply on generation[i] since all values are undefined... Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `generation[i]` is an array of `undefined` values.

```
generation[i] = new Array(gene_size);
```

No wonder you're getting back NaN. You're trying to find the max value from a bunch of nothing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fygcr/).

Comment: I second this, it makes no sense.The max individual should be counted at the end,probably

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, because there is no specific data type in JavaScript.